# VLOOKUP displaying wrong information in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

new to excel, and trying to do a simple task, where depending on the months in a month range, some percentage will be displayed. However, it's always displaying 0.

Here's a picture to help you understand:

For example, F3 should display 15%

[image: For example, F3 should display 15%]

Thanks in advance, and apologies if I'm not using the correct format, it's my first time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out where the issue was, I had set the type of cell to currency; so I just switched it to percentage and it worked.

Leaving the post in case someone can find it useful.

Comment: BTW, instead of `VLOOKUP()` you could use only `LOOKUP()` function: `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(D3,$I$4:$K$6),0)`

Comment: Also its not just abt setting the cell formattng as currency bt the decimla places were `0` hence why you were not getting to see the actual values, otherwise it would have shown as `$0.15`

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason the `VLOOKUP()` returned value was showing `0` because the **decimal places** were set to `0` and not just because of the currency type. Cell formatted to as `Currency` and **decimal places** were set to `2` it would have shown as `$0.15` . `VLOOKUP()` does work, but its just **decimal places** which made the difference.

Cell set to `0` **decimal places** with data type as `Currency` will show as below, -- `Before`

[image]

---

Cell set to `2` **decimal places** with data type as `Currency` will shows as below, -- `After`

[image]

---

One needs to change the cell data type to `Percentage` as well as keep the **decimals places** to at least `2`

[image]

---

**BTW**, since its an **approximate match operation**, instead of `VLOOKUP()` one can use `LOOKUP()` function as well:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP([@[Meses vencimiento]],$I$4:$K$6),0)
```

---